# netty-socketio integration with Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, socket.io

I'm thinking of using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for a real time web app written in Java. From what I see socket.io server is mainly developed for Node.js and there are ports for it in Java. Seems [netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) is a stable solution.

I can't figure out though if I can embed it in a WAR file within my application running on Tomcat8 and have no issue running it like that.

Has anyone integrated this within a WAR file in Tomcat8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as easy as pie, just create `com.corundumstudio.socketio.SocketIOServer`. Example:

In your tomcat Servlet.init method type follow:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setHostname("localhost");
config.setPort(81);

SocketIOServer server = new SocketIOServer(config);
server.start();
```

Comment: @Nikita Koksharov: so basically I'm spawning a new process that listens on another port?

Comment: @JohnDoDo SocketIOServer spawns it for you

Comment: @Nikita Koksharov: I'll give it a try! Thanks!

Comment: @Nikita Koksharov, i have app(spring boot) running on tomcat(port : 8080). i would like to use SocketIOServer with the same port(8080). i did some googling but i did not find the solution . is it possible to reuse the same port for SocketIoServer