# How to implement netty-socketio in tomcat?

Tags: socket.io, netty, java-websocket, netty-socketio

I am using socketio framework for frontend. socket.io does not provide any frameworks for Java. I found the Netty's SocketIO framework for the backend. But, I am not found any example for this framework (integrates with Tomcat).

I look out the sample project https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio-demo of Netty's SocketIO. But, I can't understand the code. I don't know even where I have to start?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [netty-socketio integration with Tomcat8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331927/netty-socketio-integration-with-tomcat8)